# Django Admin ForeignKey field widget options and inconsistent defaults

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model that has foreign keys, and in the admin those FKs render as drop-down lists. However, some of them show buttons for 'add', 'edit', and 'delete' of the elements in the related table, and others do not. I cannot figure out what is different between the fields such that some render one way and some render a different way.

My ideal situation is that those buttons **do not** render for any foreign keys, that editing one model is restricted to just changes on that entity itself.

I see that Django ultimately selects the `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper` for these fields. I can set `can_add_related`, `can_change_related`, and `can_delete_related` on this widget, but I don't see how to easily pass these as options for these fields so that they are all consistent.

How do I manage turning these options on and off in the admin?

Answer (score 0):

New a staff user(not superuser) in admin,assume model A has foreignkey named model B,assign add/change/delete perms of model A and add perm of model B to that user,use that user to login admin,you can and only can add model B in admin panel or `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`.Because can_xxx_related is cal in admin by perms by:

```
                wrapper_kwargs.update(
                    can_add_related=related_modeladmin.has_add_permission(request),
                    can_change_related=related_modeladmin.has_change_permission(request),
                    can_delete_related=related_modeladmin.has_delete_permission(request),
                )
```

code in `django\contrib\admin\options.py\line 162`